# Google Cloud Build stalling when running more than 4 triggers simultaneously

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

So I have this issue where when I try to run Cloud Build triggers they will sometimes just stall and block the cloud build pipeline I have.

So for example I ran ~10 builds simultaneously below and as expected the first one executed and deployed just fine but the remaining ones just kept loading indefinitely until they expired.

Is there anyway I can fix this? Sometimes I'll upload changes to my git repo that affect 20+ different cloud functions and it's extremely cumbersome having to submit commits in batches of 3-4 functions at a time to avoid clogging cloud build and having to wait 1 hour for them to expire.

(Pic below)

Also I checked my quotas and saw that the "Regional Concurrent builds per region" for the region all my cloud functions is in has never even surpassed 50% capacity so this doesn't seem to be the issue

Any help would be highly appreciated

[image]

Comment: what do the Cloud Build logs say?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Either "Build failed with status EXPIRED" or "... is taking too long". Looking at the execution details I'll see that the build was queue'd for the whole duration (30m) and then expired.

Or it'll say it was building the deployment for 30m and then failed, which makes no sense as builds never take longer than 4 minutes when I'm running <=4 concurrent builds